# How to include the index of each file name in the listing when using a for-each loop

Tags: java, bluej

I am working on a challenge exercise whereas I'm using bluej. Here you have the code I'm struggling with:

```
public void listAllfiles()
{
    for(String filename : files) {
        System.out.println(filename);
    }
}
```

I am supposed to improve this method by including the index of each file name in the listing when I print. I seem to be stuck after numerous attempts at getting it right. I know that I need a local variable of "position" in the method, as well as a statement to update its value by one inside the for-each loop. I just can't get it right.

Comment: What type is `files`?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as this:

```
int count = 0;
for(String filename : files) {
    System.out.println(String.format("files[%s]: %s", count++, filename));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to change the for loop from an enhanced for each loop `for(... : ...)` to a regular indexed for loop `for(...; ...; ...)`:

(Note that intellij idea has a refactor for this, just position the cursor on the token `for` and click the lightbulb and select: "Replace 'for each' loop with indexed 'for' loop" but I doubt bluej is that useful so you'll have to do it manually)

Assuming `files` is an array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    System.out.println(i + ": " + files[i]);
}
```

Comment: Was this any help to you? Please upvote or accept helpful suggestions.